# Load, filter data from firebase and show specific data

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I use angular cli, firebase and angularfire2.

I have DetailComponent whose url is

```
/ 'Patient /' + key
```

and I have data (diagnostics) of this type:

```
  -diagnostics
    -LFHnjAs7NSb6GhsZdIA
       key: "-LF2eRf1lHI6X3U6C7Yh"
       localisation: "qfdsdfsdfsdf"

    -LFHz_O9jsPqJs-vRK9Y
       key: "-LF2eRf1lHI6X3U6C7Yh"
       localisation: "SFQSFSQDFSDF"

    -LFHz_sNmClDkcRXkiQd
       key: "-LF2eRf1lHI6X3U6C7Yh"
       localisation: "DSFSDFSDF"
```

Is it possible to request firebase to browse all the child objects of the node "diagnosis" and it shows all objects whose item "key" is equal to the value of my url? (my url is the value of the key I want to play)

Maybe, the question could be how to filter my data by my item "key" = "activedroute"

Thank you for your help !

Hi , i tried this :

//Service :

```
 getSingleDiagnostic(Patientid: string){return this.database.list('/diagnostics', ref => ref.orderByChild("key").equalTo(Patientid)).valueChanges();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("diagnostics")
ref.orderByChild("key").equalTo("-LF2eRf1lHI6X3U6C7Yh")
```

To pass this into AngularFire2:

```
db.list('/diagnostics', ref => ref.orderByChild("key").equalTo("-LF2eRf1lHI6X3U6C7Yh"))
```

See the [AngularFire2 documentation on querying lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md).

Comment: Thank you Frank ! I think it s that i search but i want replace "-LF2eRf1lHI6X3U6C7Yh" by my url like that : {this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters)=> { this.Patientid = urlParameters['id'];});

Comment: Maybe just put this code inside the keyvalue ?  all of the code must be in the component and not in a service ? thank you for your help

Comment: It seems like you're trying something already, but can't get it to work. In that case, the best way to get help is by [creating a minimal, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question (there's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50916243/edit) link under it).

Comment: Yes Thank you Franck i test this tomorow and comeback. Have a nice day